# How do I dynamically size a GridView Item?

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a Grid View that is used to display "tags" which is a list of strings that are dynamic in size.  Using the following code:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}" 
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TagTemplate}" 
          VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
          Grid.RowSpan="2"
          SelectionMode="None"
          />
```

I use the following Template for the items:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="TagTemplate">
    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="75">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

When added to the Grid, the size of each of the items are the same size as the first:

[image]

How do I dynamically size the items within the GridView?

Comment: Is the size of your GridView dynamic or static? Any way you can use the `RowDataBound` event to change the cell size depending on the values inserted.

Comment: @Nick.T It's statically sized, however the tags are scrollable as [seen here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2kQn.png).

Comment: Why not just use an ItemsControl with a StackPanel or WrapPanel as your ItemsPanelTemplate instead? You can easily get the same look you're going for.

Comment: @ChrisW. Mainly because I didn't know about it :P  That seems to be exactly what I want, with the exception that I wasn't able to get the items to be scrollable.

Comment: Put them in a ScrollViewer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like;

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}">
        <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                <!-- Or use WrapPanel depending on its display -->
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="75" Padding="3" Margin="3,0">
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </Border>                             
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Of course this is not really resizing the GridView; the only way to resize a GridView is to use the VariableSizedWrapGrid

Comment: Nah, it eliminates the GridView all together with another alternative.

Comment: @JerryNixon How would you do that?

Comment: See the only thing I don't like about the gridview, is all cells are the same dimensions, I use ItemsControl's a lot more for more flexible design instances. At least that was part of my thinking for this instance anyway.

Comment: You can also add Row/ColumnDefinitions for the Grid and set it to "auto" which will calculate the optimal size of the row/column.