# WinRT XAML - How to strech button horizontal in ListView

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to horizontal strech button inside ListView, but my xaaml code doesn't work:

```
        <ListView Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Grid.Row="2" Background="White" BorderThickness="4,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#8c0095" Margin="32,-3,32,17" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="#8c0095" FontSize="20" Margin="15,1,0,10" FontWeight="Medium" />

                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You have a 32unit margin left and right is that intentional? Just asking cos that's probably why you think button aint stretching.

Comment: Yes it is intentional, but if I delete that margin, button ain't strech too.

Comment: you want the button to stretch all the way across the ListView ?  Does this get you want you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067309/listviewitem-wont-stretch-to-the-width-of-a-listview