# ListView first item missing when binding width

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

i have this xaml code:

```
<ListView Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=MyList, Path=ActualWidth}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding aaa}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding bbb}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ccc}" 
                            TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Height="25" MaxHeight="25"  Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ListTitle}" Text="{Binding restaDaPagare}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                    <Canvas Grid.Column="2" Height="50" Width="50" Background="{StaticResource GrayBrush}"></Canvas>
                    <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="/Images/img.png" 
                                   Height="50" Width="50" MinHeight="50" MinWidth="50"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

For some reasons, if i use this instruction (row 5):

```
<Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=MyList, Path=ActualWidth}">
```

the first item of MyList disappears.
If i use this code:

```
<Grid Width="400">
```

everything works well... except that I don't want to use a static Width.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does anybody know _why_ binding the width does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to not set any width for your Grid (in your template) and add this to your ListView

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This idea was "taken" from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067309/listviewitem-wont-stretch-to-the-width-of-a-listview)

Comment: Thanks a lot... this worked! I've probably missed the response where you took the idea because it haven't windows phone tag.