# ListView ItemTemplate Grid 100% Width

Tags: xaml, responsive-design, user-controls, windows-phone-8.1

I have made an ListView ItemTemplate and I want it to be responsive (when orientation changes, for example, the listView item changes in size). I am using a Grid as a control for the inner elements of the grid but it is not behaving. The ListView.ItemContainerStyle has property HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" which is the behaviour I want, and the ItemContainerStyle is the correct width. Inside the Border and Grid I have the same HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" and they are overflowing when the TextBox contained inside has lots of text, and when there is little or no text in the TextBox the Border element shrinks to be smaller than the ItemContainerStyle is showing.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TileStories}" x:Name="cont" Margin="0,10,0,10" Background="{StaticResource CustomResourceBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource CustomResourceBrush}" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomResourceBrush}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,10,20,10" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BTVioletBrush}" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border CornerRadius="20" BorderThickness="0" Width="{Binding ScrollViewerWidth}" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <StackPanel Height="160" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Grid Background="black">
                            <TextBox Text="Example">
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Isn't this a [duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15067309/2681948)? Have you tried to set *HorizontalContentAlignment*?

Comment: That fixed part of the problem - the white background for the "border" is now behaving properly but the grid (if I remove the fixed width) should be bound by the width of the border and it's overflowing to the right because of the textbox.

Comment: I have just edited the code to simplify the problem but am still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you share a sample minimal project with the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't exactly find a solution but I did find a workaround. The Grid was being bound with `Width="0"` if I used `{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=StackPanel, Mode=OneWay}` where `StackPanel` was the panel within the data template. I was poking around the designer in VS2013 and figured out that the `Width` was 0 because (I am assuming) the items in the data template are drawn one by one and therefore the `Width` was zero when the first template was drawn and so on and so forth. I haven't explained that very well I guess, but the important thing is the solution:

```
<PivotItem x:Name="Feed">
    ....
    <Border CornerRadius="20" BorderThickness="0" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel Height="160" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Feed, Mode=OneWay}">
            ........
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
...
</PivotItem>
```

I think that the `PivotItem` having a non-variable `Width` meant the `Grid` had a concrete `Width` to inherit from.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define MinHeight as 0 for ItemContainerStyle

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything

Comment: Can you provide a sample project ?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your ItemContainerStyle

```
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                    Value="Stretch" />
```

And I think `Width="{Binding ScrollViewerWidth}"` is not required. You can remove this.

Comment: That was removed and had no effect on the size