# Set ListView100% of screen width (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have ListView in my UWP app and want it to set 100% of width of display.

Here is my code in xaml file

```
<Page
x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView x:Name="PostList" ItemsSource="{Binding PostsList}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="720" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1280">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="GridInf"  Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
            </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

I try to do like this `Width="100%"`

But it not works?

How I can make it?

Comment: Don't set the width for ListView then It will take 100% of the screen

Comment: Nope, it not takes 100%@VijayNirmal

Comment: Change your `ListView` `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[UWP\]\[XAML\] ListView child item not using full width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38135361/uwpxaml-listview-child-item-not-using-full-width)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Don't set the width for ListView
2. Set `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` or don't set it

Here is your modified code

```
<ListView x:Name="PostList" ItemsSource="{Binding PostsList}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="720" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="GridInf"  Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```