# How to show full webview2 in listview in WinUI 3?

Tags: xaml, listview, winui-3, webview2, winui

I have a `ListView` that contains a `DataTemplate` that displays a `WebView2` for each item. The default behavior of the `ListView` appears to be smashing the `WebView` down to a `0` height.

This is the setup for what I have:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyObservableCollection, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:MyViewModel">
            <WebView2 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Source="https://www.google.com"><WebView2>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**The behavior I would like**, is for the `WebView` to expand vertically to show the entire html content it contains, without scrolling. Thus, the only scrolling is the `ListView` itself scrolling. Setting a fixed height or a minimum height does force the WebView to display, but this is not a viable solution. I cannot predict the height of the contents in advance, the height may vary, and a minimum height just results in ALL items being exactly that minimum height in the `ListView`. **How can I get this behavior?**

The real-world example of this desired behavior (and the inspiration for this) is an email thread in the right-hand pane of the new Outlook app - each email body is shown vertically in full (an item in the `ListView`) but the whole `ListView`still scrolls.

I have tried manipulating the `ItemContainerStyle` (as in the example below, modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067309/listviewitem-wont-stretch-to-the-width-of-a-listview)) but **this does not work** to get my desired behavior:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Additionally, neither `VerticalContentAlignment` nor `VerticalAlignment` worked.

I know that `ListView` uses an `ItemsStackPanel` to contain the list, and I know that `StackPanel` has a similar issue like this, if that helps. There is a warning in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/listview-and-gridview) about performance hits to using a different container than the `ItemsStackPanel`, but I am open to this if it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: You can add [ListViewItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.listviewitem?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4)s with Height programmatically if you know the desired height.